# Exibir div após enviar e-mails via POST Ajax PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Estou aprendendo a enviar e-mail via POST no Ajax.
O que tenho está certo, a única coisa é que depois do envio do e-mail, ele não carrega o formulário (retornoHTML), ficando um buraco na tela:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- Sweetalert -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/sweetalert-master/dist/sweetalert.css">     

        <title>Enviando e-mail com AJAX e PHP via protocolo SMTP - Vinteum Desenvolvimento</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        <script>
            $(document).ready( function(){ //Quando documento estiver pronto
                $('#btn').click( function(){ /* Quando clicar em #btn */
                    /* Coletando dados */
                    var nome  = $('#nome').val(); 
                    var email = $('#email').val(); 
                    var msg   = $('#msg').val();                                            

                    /* Validando */
                    // if(nome.length <= 3){           
                    //     alert('Informe seu nome');                        
                    //     return false;           
                    // }                         
                    // if(email.length <= 5){           
                    //     alert('Informe seu email');                        
                    //     return false;           
                    // }      
                    // if(msg.length <= 5){           
                    //     alert('Escreva uma mensagem');                    
                    //     return false;           
                    // }                     

                    /* construindo url */
                    var urlData = "&nome=" + nome + "&email=" + email + "&msg=" + msg ;

                    /* Ajax */
                    $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: "sendmail.php", /* endereço do phpmailer */
                         async: true,
                         data: urlData, /* informa Url */
                         success: function(data) { /* sucesso */
                             $('#retornoHTML').html(data);
                         },
                         beforeSend: function() { /* antes de enviar */
                             $('.loading').fadeIn('fast'); 
                         },
                         complete: function(){ /* completo */               
                             $('.loading').fadeOut('fast');
                         }
                     });
                });    
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            .loading { display: none; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <h1><a href="http://vinteum.com/enviando-email-com-ajax-php-smtp">Enviando e-mail com AJAX e PHP via protocolo SMTP</a></h1>
        <em>Vinteum Desenvolvimento</em>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>        
        <div id="retornoHTML">
            <form>            
                Nome<br>
                <input id="nome" maxlength="10" type="text"><br>
                E-mail<br>
                <input id="email" maxlength="15" value="james@server.com" type="text"><br>
                Mensagem:<br>
                <textarea cols="50" rows="7" id="msg" maxlength="50"></textarea><br>
                <input type="button" id="btn" value="ENVIAR">
                <img src="loading.gif" class="loading">
            </form>
        </div>                 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: faça o seguinte no sucess do ajax ao inves de usar o html use isso, $('#retornoHTML').append(data); se funcionar posto como resposta e explico

Comment: Teria como mostrar o arquivo sendmail.php?

Comment: O que é exatamente `carrega o formulário (retornoHTML)` pois ao que parece vc quer carregar  `urlData` na div `retornoHTML`

Comment: sendmail
<?php
/*
 * modelo para utilização da classe PHPMailer 
 */

//echo 'Mensagem enviada com sucesso.<br><a href="http://vinteum.com/?p=1878">VOLTAR PARA TUTORIAL</a>'; //retorno (html) devolvido para o ajax caso sucesso

echo "
              <script type=\"text/javascript\">
               swal({ 
                title: \"Enviado\",
                text: \"Agradecemos seu contato!\",
                confirmButtonColor: \"#FF6000\",
                type: \"success\" 
               });
              </script>
";
?>

Comment: Se eu colocar $('#retornoHTML').append(data); funciona, mas agora os campos do formulário ficam preenchidos.

Answer (score 1):

Para carregar o valor da variável `urlData` na div `retornoHTML` após a requisição ser bem-sucedida:

```
success: function(data) { /* sucesso */
    $("#retornoHTML").html(urlData);
},
.....................
```