# Como desocultar a div de sucesso ou erro após envio de formulário?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Possuo o seguinte formulário:

```
<form action="./email.php" method="POST">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" name="name">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefone" name="phone">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Empresa" name="company">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Como nós podemos te ajudar?" name="message"></textarea>
                  <input type="submit" class="main-btn" value="Enviar">
                </form>
```

Ele está sendo executado através do seguinte código PHP:

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {

    $name = addslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
    $phone = addslashes($_POST['phone']);
    $company = addslashes($_POST['company']);
    $message = addslashes($_POST['message']);


    $to = "contato@site.com.br";
    $subject = "Contato - Formulário";
    $body =   "Nome: "    .$name."\r\n".
              "E-mail: "  .$email."\r\n".
              "Telefone: ".$phone."\r\n".
              "Empresa: " .$company."\r\n".
              "Mensagem: ".$message;
    $header = "From:contato@site.com.br"."\r\n".
              "Reply-To:".$email."\r\n".
              "X=Mailer:PHP/".phpversion();


    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)){
      echo ("E-mail enviado com sucesso!");
    } else {
      echo ("O e-mail não pode ser enviado.");
    };
  }
?>
```

No lugar das mensagens de "echo" que estão no PHP, eu gostaria de retirar a classe "d-none" de uma das divs abaixo, ocultadas de propósito, esperando o sucesso ou erro do envio do formulário, sem sair da página que o usuário se encontra:

```
<div class="alert alert-success d-none" role="alert">
                    E-mail enviado! Você será respondido em breve.
                  </div>
                  <div class="alert alert-danger d-none" role="alert">
                    Erro ao enviar e-mail, tente novamente!
                  </div>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Se houver outro método para obter o mesmo resultado de mensagem de envio de formulário, sou todo ouvidos.
Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optei por utilizar o `Ajax` com `Jquery`, para isso inseri no `header` o `CDN` que vc pode conseguir [aqui](https://releases.jquery.com/).

No **formulário** a única mudança significativa que fiz foi retirar a `action` e o `method` da tag `form`.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-1" placeholder="Nome" name="name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-1" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-1" placeholder="Telefone" name="phone">
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-1" placeholder="Empresa" name="company">
    <textarea class="form-control mb-1" rows="3" placeholder="Como nós podemos te ajudar?" name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Reparei que vc está usando o `Bootstrap`, por causa da classe `form-control` nos `inputs`, sendo assim, criei uma estrutura `html` para exibir as mensagens logo abaixo do `form`.

```
<div class="col-12 mt-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="alert d-none" role="alert" id="message"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Perceba que trata-se de uma estrutura genérica, pois as classes de **sucesso** ou **erro** e a **mensagem** vamos acrescentar depois.

**REQUISIÇÃO AJAX**

```
<script>
    //captura o evento de envio do formulário
    $('form').on('submit', (e) => {
        //desabilita o comportamento padrão do botão submit
        e.preventDefault()
        //serializa o formulário
        let data = $('form').serialize()
        //configurando a requisição ajax
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: data,
            success: (response) => {
            /**
             * O código 1 é retornado pelo PHP em caso de sucesso.
             * A div com id='message' recebe a classe alert-success ou alert-danger 
             * e remove a classe d-none, por fim adiciona a mensagem.
             */
             response == 1 
                 ? $('#message').addClass('alert-success').removeClass('alert-danger d-none').html('E-mail enviado! Você será respondido em breve.') 
                 : $('#message').addClass('alert-danger').removeClass('alert-success d-none').html('Erro ao enviar e-mail, tente novamente!')
             }
         });
    }) //submit
  <script>
```

Já no arquivo `PHP` o que alterei foi apenas esse trecho de código:

```
if ( mail($to, $subject, $body, $header) ){
    //para sucesso
    echo 1;
} else {
    //para erro
    echo -1;
};
```

Com base nesse retorno (1 ou -1) exibiremos o respectivo `alert`.

Talvez não seja a melhor ou mais elegante, no entanto, foi a forma mais fácil que encontrei para responder sua pergunta.

Veja mais sobre Ajax com Jquery [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score -2):

[...]
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)){
echo ("E-mail enviado com sucesso!");
$msn = 1;
} else {
echo ("O e-mail não pode ser enviado.");
$msn = 0;
};
[...]
[...]
<div class="alert alert-success <?= ($msn==1)?'d-none':'';?>" role="alert">
[...]

<div class="alert alert-danger <?= ($msn==0)?'d-none':'';?>" role="alert">
[...]
O nome desse condicional é "Operador ternário"
contição ? "true" : "false" ;
<?= $var;?>  é a mesma coisa de <?php echo $var;?>

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Obrigado irmão. Testei, mas ficou funcionando do mesmo jeito. Não está faltando declarar a variável $msn antes?

Comment: @J.Louzada se você quer submeter um código que não saia da página atual, talvez você precise usar AJAX(javascript ou Jquery por exemplo).
Assim você submete seu formulário e retorna a resposta em um alguma DIV, sem sair da página atual(que é a forma dinâmica de fazer requisições).
[link] https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240200/exibir-div-ap%c3%b3s-enviar-e-mails-via-post-ajax-php